# Why does this function bring null values?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have made a function in a view to calculate a league. The problem is that the function gives me the next error when I try to see the view.
 ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value
ORA-06512: at "project.league", line 24
06503. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Function returned without value"

This is my function code.

```
create or replace FUNCTION leaguepts(Team preleague.Team1%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
cumulpts NUMBER(3):=1;
cumulpts2 NUMBER(3):=2;
cumulpts3 NUMBER(3):=0;
VT matches.Team1%TYPE;
texist EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(Team1) INTO VT FROM matches WHERE Team1=Team; 
IF (VT>0) THEN
    SELECT SUM(PTS) INTO cumulpts FROM preleague WHERE Team2=Team;
    SELECT SUM(PTS2) INTO cumulpts2 FROM preleague WHERE Team2=Team;
    cumulpts3:=(cumulpts+cumulpts2);
ELSE
    RAISE texist;
END IF;
RETURN cumulpts3;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN texist THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The team does not exist');

END;
```

And this is my view code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "project"."league" ("Team", "PTS")   AS 
  SELECT Name, Leaguepts(team_cod) FROM Teams;
```

I wanted to do a function to know how many point each team has to see the league view like a clasification. I´ll be grateful with everyone who tries to help me.

Comment: Could that happen for a team, that has no match data?

Comment: @stickybit that couldn´t be. All the tables that I use have data

Comment: your function doesn't return a value  when exception is catched. you should do a raise or return a value

Comment: Done it! Thanks. It was my mistake in other table I apologise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Boneist - **Good point**. 
It’s not only removing unnecessary variable but (more important) unnecessary query. Context Switch or switching between SQL and PL/SQL engines impacts on performance.

I’d go even further by removing two more variables and one more SQL query:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION leaguepts (team preleague.team1%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER AS
      cumulpts  NUMBER(3) := 0;
      texist EXCEPTION;
    BEGIN

    SELECT SUM(NVL(pts, 0) + NVL(pts2, 0))
    INTO cumulpts
    FROM preleague
    WHERE  team2 = team;

    IF cumulpts > 0 THEN
      RETURN cumulpts;
    ELSE
      RAISE texist;
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
  WHEN texist THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('The team "'||team||'" does not exist');
    return null;

END leaguepts;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION leaguepts (team preleague.team1%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER AS
  cumulpts  NUMBER(3) := 0;
  cumulpts2 NUMBER(3) := 0;
  vt        matches.team1%TYPE;
  texist EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(team1)
  INTO   vt
  FROM   matches
  WHERE  team1 = team;

  IF (vt > 0)
  THEN
    SELECT SUM(pts), SUM(pts2)
    INTO   cumulpts, cumulpts2
    FROM   preleague
    WHERE  team2 = team;

  ELSE
    RAISE texist;
  END IF;

  RETURN nvl(cumulpts, 0) + nvl(cumulpts2, 0);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN texist THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('The team "'||team||'" does not exist');
    return null;

END leaguepts;
/
```

And here's a [demo of it working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff35eb1959a153d3360f276b72068874)

I have modified your function to remove the unnecessary `cumulpts3` variable, and I've also updated `cumulpts + cumulpts2` to use NVL to return a 0 if any of the values are 0 (e.g. in my example, team D exists, but has no rows in preleague, so 0 is returned, vs team B which doesn't have a team1 value in the matches table, so null is returned.

You may wish to change these values accordingly (maybe you want both to be null? In which case, remove the `NVL`s, or maybe you want to return null for the team present and -1 for a missing team, etc)